# How to show the derivative of $f(M)=\text{Tr}(M\log (M) -M)$ is $\log (M)$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $M$ be a positive definite matrix in $\mathbb{S}_+^n$. Let $\log$ be natural matrix logarithm which $\log(M)$ is defined as $\log(M)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(\lambda_i)v_iv_i^T$ where $(\lambda_i,v_i)$ are eigenpairs of $M$.

This function is called negative Von Neumann entropy or negative Quantum entropy.

How can we show the derivative of $f(M)=\text{Tr}(M\log M -M)$ is $\log M?$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{S}^n_+$?

Comment: @Jacky Chong: The set of all $n \times n$ positive definite matrices.

Comment: Do they have to be symmetric?

Comment: @Jacky Chong: Both $\mathbb{S}^n_+$ and $M$ are positive definite so the automatically are symmetric.

Comment: $\log$ of $>)$ matrices has some nice properties under the trace.

Comment: For practically any function $f$ and *any* matrix $M$ you can write 
$$\frac{\partial{\,\rm Tr}(f(M))}{\partial M} = f'(M^T)$$
When $M$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, you obtain the ordinary (scalar) derivative.

Comment: @greg: This one is a little more complicated as the derivative of the inner function is not immediate (there is no guarantee that the 'perturbation' and $M$ commute). The presence of the trace means $\log$ retains its nice property of $\log(x) - \log x + \log y$ under the trace.

Comment: @copper.hat There's nothing particularly "complicated" about this function
$$\eqalign{
f(x)  &= x\log(x) -x \cr
f'(x) &= \log(x) \cr
}$$ Is there some subtly that I'm missing?

Comment: It is a matrix function, the derivative of $M \mapsto M \log M -M$, is not $\log$ otherwise it would be trivial.

Comment: @copper.hat I think we're talking past each other.  The gradient of the trace of a function applied to a square matrix equals the ordinary derivative of the function applied to the transpose of the matrix. This hold for any analytic function.

Comment: @greg: Nice observation. The cyclic property of trace means the matrix and perturbation commute under the trace. I missed that entirely.

Comment: @greg: Very nice trick to find the derivative of trace.

Comment: @greg: where can I find the proof?

Comment: @Saeed: I added a proof for one definition of $f(M)$ below.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M\in\mathbb{S}_+^n$, there must exist a orthogonal matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda=\text{diag}\left\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n\right\}$, with each $\lambda_j>0$, such that
$$
M=U\Lambda U^{\top}.
$$
Hence, using the definition of $\log M$,
\begin{align}
M\log M-M&=\left(U\Lambda U^{\top}\right)\left(U\log\Lambda\,U^{\top}\right)-U\Lambda U^{\top}\\
&=U\left(\Lambda\log\Lambda-\Lambda\right)U^{\top}.
\end{align}
Consequently,
\begin{align}
f(M)&=\text{tr}\left(M\log M-M\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(U\left(\Lambda\log\Lambda-\Lambda\right)U^{\top}\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\left(\Lambda\log\Lambda-\Lambda\right)U^{\top}U\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\Lambda\log\Lambda-\Lambda\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\left(\log\lambda_j-1\right).
\end{align}
Therefore, it follows that
$$
{\rm d}f(M)=\sum_{j=1}^n\log\lambda_j\,{\rm d}\lambda_j=\text{tr}\left(\log\Lambda\,{\rm d}\Lambda\right).
$$

On the other hand,
\begin{align}
\log M\,{\rm d}M&=\left(U\log\Lambda\,U^{\top}\right){\rm d}\left(U\Lambda U^{\top}\right)\\
&=\left(U\log\Lambda\,U^{\top}\right)\left({\rm d}U\Lambda U^{\top}+U{\rm d}\Lambda\,U^{\top}+U\Lambda\,{\rm d}U^{\top}\right)\\
&=U\log\Lambda\,U^{\top}\,{\rm d}U\Lambda U^{\top}+U\log\Lambda\,{\rm d}\Lambda U^{\top}+U\log\Lambda\,\Lambda\,{\rm d}U^{\top}.
\end{align}
Take the trace of both sides, and the first and the last term on the right-hand side cancel out (to be explained soon). Thus we obtain
\begin{align}
\text{tr}\left(\log M\,{\rm d}M\right)&=\text{tr}\left(U\log\Lambda\,{\rm d}\Lambda U^{\top}\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\log\Lambda\,{\rm d}\Lambda U^{\top}U\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\log\Lambda\,{\rm d}\Lambda\right)\\
&={\rm d}f(M).
\end{align}
This result implies that, in the form,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial M}f(M)=\log M.
$$

---

In this appendix, let us explain the cancel-out of the two traces. In fact,
\begin{align}
\text{tr}\left(U\log\Lambda\,U^{\top}\,{\rm d}U\Lambda U^{\top}\right)&=\text{tr}\left({\rm d}U\Lambda U^{\top}\,U\log\Lambda\,U^{\top}\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left({\rm d}U\Lambda\log\Lambda\,U^{\top}\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left({\rm d}U\log\Lambda\,\Lambda\,U^{\top}\right)\\
&=\text{tr}\left(\log\Lambda\,\Lambda\,U^{\top}{\rm d}U\right)\\
&=-\text{tr}\left(\log\Lambda\,\Lambda\,{\rm d}U^{\top}\,U\right)\\
&=-\text{tr}\left(U\log\Lambda\,\Lambda\,{\rm d}U^{\top}\right),
\end{align}
where we have repeatedly used the identity
$$
\text{tr}\left(AB\right)=\text{tr}\left(BA\right)
$$
for square matrices $A$ and $B$, the orthogonality
$$
U^{\top}U=UU^{\top}=I_n,
$$
and its differentiation
$$
\mathbf{0}={\rm d}\left(U^{\top}U\right)={\rm d}U^{\top}\,U+U^{\top}\,{\rm d}U.
$$

Comment: The map $M \to \Lambda(M)$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @hypernova: what is $SO(n)$?

Comment: @Saeed: Oops, it should be $O(n)$, [orthogonal group of order $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group). I changed the description, just in case.

Comment: @copper.hat: Could you explain what is $\Lambda(M)$? and what does this map do? I was thinking because $M$ is positive definite it is continuous. Also, which part of hypernova's answer is flawed?

Comment: @hypernova: Could you substitute $O$ with zero $(\textbf{0})$ in the last line?

Comment: @Saeed: Sure. Revised as per your request.

Comment: @Saeed: The map from $M$ to the eigenvalues is not differentiable.

Comment: @copper.hat: You are right. It is differentiable only if eigenvalues are distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Well. Observe
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}(M\log M-M) = \operatorname{Tr}(M\log M)-\operatorname{Tr}(M).
\end{align}
Using the Gateaux variation, observe that
\begin{align}
 \operatorname{Tr}\left(N\frac{d\operatorname{Tr}M}{dM} \right)=\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}(M+tN)\big|_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt} \sum_{i=1}^n(M_{ii}+tN_{ii})\bigg|_{t=0} = \operatorname{Tr}(N)
\end{align}
for any $N$. Hence $\frac{d\operatorname{Tr}M}{dM}=I$.

Likewise, we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}\left(N\frac{d\operatorname{Tr}[M\log M]}{dM} \right) = \frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}[(M+tN)\log(M+tN)]\bigg|_{t=0}.
\end{align}
Observe
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}[(M+tN)\log(M+tN)]=&\   \operatorname{Tr}[M\log M]+\operatorname{Tr}[M\log(I+tM^{-1}N)]\\
&\ + t\operatorname{Tr}[N\log M]+t\operatorname{Tr}[N\log(I+tM^{-1}N)]\\
=&\ \operatorname{Tr}[M\log M]+t\operatorname{Tr}[N(I+\log M)]+\mathcal{O}(t^2)
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}[(M+tN)\log(M+tN)]\bigg|_{t=0} = \operatorname{Tr}[N(I+\log M)]
\end{align}
for any $N$. Hence it follows $\frac{d\operatorname{Tr}[M\log M]}{dM}=I+\log M$. Thus we have the desired result.

Note, I used the fact that $M$ is positive definite when I claim that $M$ is invertible and $\log M$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for small $H$ we have $\log (I+H) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} {1 \over k} H^k$.

Also note that for $A,B$ positive definite we have $\operatorname{tr} (\log (AB)) = \operatorname{tr} (\log A) + \operatorname{tr}  ( \log B)$.

Going straight for the Fréchet derivative, we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(M+H) -f(M)&=& \operatorname{tr} [ (M+H) \log(M+H)-M \log M -H] \\
&=& \operatorname{tr} [ (M+H) \log(M(I+M^{-1}H))-M \log M -H] \\
&=& \operatorname{tr} [ (M+H) (\log M + \log(I+M^{-1}H))-M \log M -H] \\
&=& \operatorname{tr} [ H \log M+(M+H)\log(I+M^{-1}H))  -H] \\
&=& \operatorname{tr} [ H \log M+(M+H)\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} {1 \over k} (M^{-1}H)^k-H] \\
&=& \operatorname{tr} [ H \log M+ g(H)] \\
\end{eqnarray}
where $\|g(H)\| \le K \|H\|^2$. Hence
$Df(M)H = \operatorname{tr} (\log M H) = \langle \log M , H \rangle$.

**Addendum**: @greg suggested a simpler approach in the comments in the question, here is a proof for an analytic $g$ defined on a simply connected open domain $D$  and $f(M) = \operatorname{tr} g(M)$.

Let $\gamma$ be a curve contained in $D$ and which encircles the spectrum of $M$ once (that is, $I(\gamma,\lambda) = 1$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $M$).
Let $\phi_M(z) = (zI-M)^{-1}$.
Let $g(A) = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_\gamma g(z) \phi_M(z)dz$.

A straightforward computation shows that
$Dg(A)H = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_\gamma g(z) \phi_M(z)H\phi_M(z)dz$, and so
$D f(A)H = \operatorname{tr} (Dg(A)H)  = \operatorname{tr}[{1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_\gamma g(z) \phi_M^2(z)dzH]$. Integration by parts shows that
${1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_\gamma g(z) \phi_M^2(z)dz = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_\gamma g'(z) \phi_M(z)dz = g'(M)$, and so
$Df(M)H = \operatorname{tr}(g'(M)H)$.

In particular, the gradient is $(g'(M))^T = g'(M^T)$.

Comment: Frechet derivative exist and it is $\log(M)$,true?

Comment: @Saeed: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We will utilize the fact that ${\rm tr}(A - B) = {\rm tr}(A) - {\rm tr}(B)$ and denote ${\rm tr}(AB) = \langle A^T, B \rangle := A^T : B$. Also, utilize the cyclic property of trace and denote the identity matrix by $I$.

Now compute differential and then gradient. 
\begin{align}
df &= d\:{\rm tr}\left(M \log(M) - M\right)\\
   &= d\:\left[{\rm tr}\left(M \log(M)\right) - {\rm tr}(M)\right]\\
   &= d\:\left[M^T:\log(M) - I:M\right]\\
   &= d\:\left[M^T:\log(M)\right] - I:dM\\
   &= \left[dM^T:\log(M) + M^T:M^{-1}dM\right] - I:dM\\
   &= \left[\log(M):dM^T + M^{-T}M^T:dM\right] - I:dM\\
   &= \left[\log(M)^T:dM + I:dM\right] - I:dM\\
   &= \left[\log(M)^T:dM \right] \ .
\end{align}

The gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial M} = \log(M)^T = \log(M) \hspace{5mm} \{\textrm{ since }M^T = M\}.
\end{align}